# Update node.js on pi zero w

Tags: pi-zero-w, node.js

I'm trying to update my node.js version following this tutorial: https://desertbot.io/blog/nodejs-git-and-pm2-headless-raspberry-pi-install

But at the command:

```
sudo cp -R node-v11.15.0-linux-armv6l/* /usr/local/
```

I'm getting this error:

```
cp: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/bin/node': Text file busy
```

I've searched around the internet for solutions, but didn't find any. I also tried to use "mv" like:

```
sudo mv node-v11.15.0-linux-armv6l/* /usr/local/
```

But then I'm getting these errors:

```
mv: cannot move 'node-v11.15.0-linux-armv6l/bin' to '/usr/local/bin': Directory not empty
mv: cannot move 'node-v11.15.0-linux-armv6l/include' to '/usr/local/include': Directory not empty
mv: cannot move 'node-v11.15.0-linux-armv6l/lib' to '/usr/local/lib': Directory not empty
mv: cannot move 'node-v11.15.0-linux-armv6l/share' to '/usr/local/share': Directory not empty
```

All I really just want to, is to update the node.js version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. This made it work:

```
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.10.0/node-v8.10.0-linux-armv6l.tar.xz

cd /usr/local

sudo tar xf ~/node-v8.10.0-linux-armv6l.tar.xz --strip=1

rm -rf node-v*
```

I not sure why. Seems like the above code extracts the content in the right folder instead of doing af copy / paste

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Comment: @Ingo Sure! Was just waiting as you can’t press it immediately m. Thanks for reminding me